# Change launcher icon and name for each flavour in Android Project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I will have four flavours in my app each flavour will have a different name and launcher icon.  My question is, how do I achieve this?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830972/different-app-names-for-different-build-flavors) which actually answers my question.  However, I have alot of assets in my app and I don't want to have to duplicate my res folder four times for a string and an icon, this seems very inefficient.

Is there a more efficient method of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flavour specific resource folders are applied on top of the main one. You could keep all the common assets in the main res directory and put the launcher icon and a strings file containing only the app name in the flavoured directories.

Comment: Excellent, I thought at it needed duplication.  Thank you