# Localizing string resources added via build.gradle using "resValue"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-resources, android-productflavors

This is in continuation to an answer which helped me on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30879430/1957401)

We can add the string resource as follows from `build.gradle`:

> ```
> productFlavors {
>     main{
>         resValue "string", "app_name", "InTouch Messenger"
>     }
>
>     googlePlay{
>         resValue "string", "app_name", "InTouch Messenger: GPE Edition"
>     }
> }
> ```

It works like a charm and serves the purpose of having different app names per flavor. (with the original `app_name` string resource deleted from `strings.xml` file.

But, how do we add localized strings for this string resource added from `build.gradle` ?

Is there an additional parameter we can pass specifying the locale?
**OR**
Possible to do it using a `gradle` task?

**Note:** I cannot do this using `strings.xml` (not feasible because of several ways in which my project is structured)

Comment: I think that if you need to localize it, then probably shouldn't be on the gradle. The main use there is to have, for example, two different API keys, one for Prod, one for Dev.

Comment: in my case the product flavors are not for environments but for different variation of the app. all of which go to production. My environments are controlled via build type. Cant go with separate xml for each flavor because i have a lot of them and ever increasing. Hence chose to do it via gradle.

Comment: Sorry for giving `strings.xml` solutions, but I don't think you can do it otherwise. If you have separation issues, you can add different `res.srcDir`s based what you're localizing, but the folder you add can contain multiple `values-<lang>/strings.xml` files.

Comment: By the way I think this will only change your launcher icon's label, maybe the title in the Settings app, but the application name in Play Store is based on what you enter in the Developer Console, and it's localized there.

Comment: yes that is what i want

Comment: Why can you not just use `src/main/res/values/strings.xml` and `src/googlePlay/res/values/strings.xml` to add your localized, flavored strings how it would be intended? Even if you could just add it to the build script, the result would be the same as if you were just using those folders.

Comment: @david those two flavors above are just what I copied from the other question. I have too many flavors to create separate folders.

Answer (score 13):

My other answer about the generated resources may be an overkill for you use case though. Base what I currently know about your project I think this one is a better fit:
(not that you can still combine this with generated resources)

src/flavor1/res/values/strings.xml

```
<string name="app_name_base">InTouch Messenger"</string>
<string name="app_name_gpe">InTouch Messenger: GPE Edition"</string>
```

src/flavor1/res/values-hu/strings.xml

```
<string name="app_name_base">InTouch Üzenetküldő"</string>
<string name="app_name_gpe">InTouch Üzenetküldő: GPE Változat"</string>
```

src/flavor2/res/values/strings.xml

```
<string name="app_name_base">Whatever Messenger"</string>
<string name="app_name_gpe">Whatever Messenger: GPE Edition"</string>
```

src/flavor2/res/values-hu/strings.xml`

```
<string name="app_name_base">Whatever Üzenetküldő"</string>
<string name="app_name_gpe">Whatever Üzenetküldő: GPE Változat"</string>
```

build.gradle

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        [flavor1, flavor3].each {
            it.res.srcDirs = ['src/flavor1/res']
        }
        [flavor2, flavor4].each {
            it.res.srcDirs = ['src/flavor2/res']
        }
    }
    productFlavors { // notice the different numbers than sourceSets
        [flavor1, flavor2].each {
            it.resValue "string", "app_name", "@string/app_name_base"
        }
        [flavor3, flavor4].each {
            it.resValue "string", "app_name", "@string/app_name_gpe"
        }
    }
}
```

This means that `flavor1/2` will have an extra unused `app_name_gpe` string resource, but that'll be taken care of by aapt:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking
        }
```

Comment: @AndroidMechanic did you have any luck with either?

Comment: No did not work how I wanted. Have created separate xmls for now. But there should be some way around this.

Answer (score 5):

If you do not have to operate on those strings, the best option is moving to `strings.xml`, but that would make you share all `res` folder between flavors.
If you generate these strings based on some property on `build.gradle`, then I think you're out of luck, unfortunately.

**EDIT:** *clarifying what I mean by* operate *above and add some options:*

By *operating on those strings* I mean some sort of concatenation with a build parameter, a reading from command line or environment variable during the build process (e.g., getting the commit SHA1 so that it's easier to trace bugs later). If no operation is necessary, `strings.xml` may be an option. But when you overwrite a `res` folder for flavor, all of it is overwritten and that could pose a problem if several flavors share the same `res` except for a limited number of strings.

If each APK has its own locale, then it's just a `resValue` or `buildConfigField` in a flavor. You can define variables to for easier reuse of values. Something like

```
def myVar = "var"

...

flavor1 {
    resValue "string", "my_res_string", "${myVar}"
}

flavor2 {
    resValue "string", "my_res_string", "${myVar}"
}
```

But if several locales are needed in the same APK and it will be chosen at runtime by Android, then the string must be in the correct `values-<locale>` folder.

Comment: Any chance we can use a task to replace the string res from build config field prior to build?

Comment: You mean so the string is fixed for a given APK? For instance, one APK only for `en_rUS` locale, other only for `pt_rBR`, other for `ja`? This way, yes, it's possible. If so, I'll update my answer. What is not possible is having multiple locales in same APK, such as what we do with `values-en`, `values-pt`, etc. For this, you'd need the `res/` folder

Comment: oh no sorry my bad. did not think it through. sorry! :) it is not fixed. need localizations for each locale.

Comment: Turns out there is currently no available way to do this without using separate strings.xml. Hence awarding the bounty to this answer. But hope there will be something made available in the framework going forward. If someone gets to know of it do post an answer here. Thanks Douglas!

Answer (score 2):

You're operating on different levels here, `BuildConfig` is code, and as such not localized, that's why we have Lint warnings for hard-coded strings. Localization in Android is done via `<string` resources, there's no way around that if you want the system to choose the language at runtime depending on user settings. There are many ways to have resources though: `values` folder, `resValue` in build.gradle, and generated resources.

You should look into the [`buildSrc` project in Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:build_sources), for example I use it to generate SQL Inserts from `src/main/values/stuff.xml`. Here's some code to start with.

buildSrc/build.gradle

```
// To enable developing buildSrc in IDEA import buildSrc/build.gradle as a separate project
// Create a settings.gradle in buildSrc as well to prevent importing as subproject
apply plugin: 'groovy'
repositories { jcenter() }
dependencies {
    compile localGroovy()
    compile gradleApi()
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

buildSrc/src/main/groovy/Plugin.groovy

```
import org.gradle.api.*
/**
 * Use it as
 * <code>
 *     apply plugin: MyPlugin
 *     myEntities {
 *         categories {
 *             input = file(path to Android res xml with Strings)
 *             output = file(path to asset SQL file)
 *             conversion = "structure|SQL"
 *         }
 *     }
 * </code>
 */
class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        def entities = project.container(MyEntity)
        // this gives the name for the block in build.gradle
        project.extensions.myEntities = entities

        def allTasks = project.task('generateYourStuff')
        def allTasksClean = project.task('cleanGenerateYourStuff')
        project.afterEvaluate {
            entities.all { entity ->
                //println "Creating task for ${entity.name} (${entity.input} --${entity.conversion}--> ${entity.output})"
                def task = project.task(type: GenerateTask, "generateYourStuff${entity.name.capitalize()}") {
                    input = entity.input
                    output = entity.output
                    conversion = entity.conversion
                }
                allTasks.dependsOn task
                // clean task is automagically generated for every task that has output
                allTasksClean.dependsOn "clean${task.name.capitalize()}"
            }
        }
    }
}
class MyEntity {
    def input
    def output
    String conversion

    final String name
    MyEntity(String name) {
        this.name = name
    }
}
```

buildSrc/src/main/groovy/GenerateTask.groovy

```
import net.twisterrob.inventory.database.*
import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask
import org.gradle.api.tasks.*
class GenerateTask extends DefaultTask {
    @InputFile File input
    @OutputFile File output
    @Optional @Input String conversion
    @TaskAction void generate() {
        input.withReader { reader ->
            // you may need to treat output as a folder
            output.parentFile.mkdirs()
            output.withWriter { writer ->
                // custom transformation here read from reader, write to writer
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is just the skeleton you can go wild and do anything from here: e.g. retrieve a CSV through the network and spread the contents into generated `variant*/res/values-*/gen.xml` files.

You can run it manually when you need to or run it at the right point in the build lifecycle (in `build.gradle`:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { com.android.build.gradle.api.ApplicationVariant variant ->
    variant.mergeAssets.dependsOn tasks.generateYourStuff
}
```

Comment: thanks! will check this one as well as soon as i'm home