# How to add text translation via resValue

Tags: android, gradle, android-resources

On our Android app we're passing strings resources via build script using the `resValue`, something like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
       resValue "string", "foo", "foo_value"
       resValue "string", "bar", "bar_value"
       ... etc
```

How to add translated version of those strings. To go on `values-de`, `values-ch`, `values-sp`, etc folders?

Comment: maybe [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105494/localizing-string-resources-added-via-build-gradle-using-resvalue) helps?

Comment: @Blackbelt not really. We're trying to inject values via CI, so in reality the values are coming from a `System.getenv(key)` command. Maybe I'll check into just download a complete `.xml` and replace in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is not possible to do it from the gradle file as mentioned [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=152198). 
If you just want to use the values, better use the [buildConfigField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30796533/how-to-generate-buildconfigfield-with-string-type) instead