# Declare variable into build.gradle that match the applicationId with flavors suffix

Tags: android, gradle, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I don't figure out how can I set a resource value (`resValue`) in my `build.gradle`, **depending on the build variant selection**.

Here a bit of explanation.

I'm working with the *Skype For Business SDK* (hereafter referred to as **Sfb**) and during is implementation, it ask me to add a resource value named `ENTERPRISE_AUTHENTICATOR_ACCOUNT_TYPE`.

So I was looking in their application example ([available here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-android-app-sdk-samples/tree/master/GuestMeetingJoin)) and found that in `build.gradle` they have added as follow the corresponding value :

```
android {
...
   defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.microsoft.office.sfb.sfbdemo"
      ...
      resValue ("string", "ENTERPRISE_AUTHENTICATOR_ACCOUNT_TYPE", "${applicationId}"
   }
   ...
}
```

This value then used in a SfbSDK class, checking if it match the application package name.

And here is my trouble, I work with different `flavorDimensions` as describe in my `build.gradle` below.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
...
android {
   ...
   defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.tsp.test"
      ...
      resValue ("string", "ENTERPRISE_AUTHENTICATOR_ACCOUNT_TYPE", "${applicationId}"
   }
   ...
   flavorDimensions("customer", "version")
   productFlavors {
      a {
         dimension "customer"
         applicationIdSuffix ".a"
      }
      b {
         dimension "customer"
         applicationIdSuffix ".b"
      }
      alpha {
         dimension "version"
         applicationIdSuffix ".alpha"
      }
      beta {
         dimension "version"
         applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
      }
      release {
         dimension "version"
         applicationIdSuffix ".release"
      }
   }
}
...
```

Depending on my *build variant* selection, this will generate me 6 different APK :

- com.tsp.test.a.alpha **;** com.tsp.test.a.beta **;** com.tsp.test.a.release
- com.tsp.test.b.alpha **;** com.tsp.test.b.beta **;** com.tsp.test.b.release

So when the match checking is does, my application crash with the message error

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: ENTERPRISE_AUTHENTICATOR_ACCOUNT_TYPE string not set to applicationId
                      at com.microsoft.office.sfb.appsdk.Application.initialize(Application.java:110)
                      at com.microsoft.office.sfb.appsdk.Application.getInstance(Application.java:144)
                      at com.tsp.test.RootActivity.onCreate(RootActivity.java:89)
```

Of course, because `com.tsp.test` doesn't match `com.tsp.test.a.alpha` (or any other APK).

How can I achieve a dynamic `resValue` depending on the *build variant* selected that match the right application package name ?

**EDIT :**

To explain a bit more. First I choose the Build Variants as follow :

- Customer : **A**
- Version  : **Alpha**

Then, in my `RootActivity#onCreate()` (my launcher activity), I start to configure the **SfbSDK** with an application instance depending on the **SfbSDK** :

```
this.mApplication = com.microsoft.office.sfb.appsdk.Application.getInstance(this.getApplication().getApplicationContext());
```

Somewhere in `getInstance()` method, the **SfbSDK** do an  `equals()` between the `context.getPackageName()` and `context.getString(string.ENTERPRISE_AUTHENTICATOR_ACCOUNT_TYPE);`

So, for debug, in my `RootActivity#onCreate()` I just wrote this two lines

```
String whatIWant = this.getPackageName(); // give me *com.tsp.test.a.alpha*
String whatIGet  = this.getString(R.string.ENTERPRISE_AUTHENTICATOR_ACCOUNT_TYPE); // give me *com.tsp.test*
```

This doesn't match ! So in SfbSDK the condition wasn't passed.

Comment: do you mean something like this? `def myVar = "var"

...

flavor1 {
    resValue "string", "my_res_string", "${myVar}"
}

flavor2 {
    resValue "string", "my_res_string", "${myVar}"
}`

Comment: this link may help (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36275537/9981067)

Comment: This is something like that except that `myVar`should match dynamically the app package name.

So something more like that :

`def appId = "com.tsp.test" + flavorDimension`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, thanks to Radesh and [this link](https://blog.davidmedenjak.com/android/2016/11/09/build-variants.html) he provided to me, I've found my solution.

I removed `resValue` from the `defaultConfig` block then I added a new block in the `android` plugin task, that create the `resValue` **for each** *variant*.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
...
android {
   ...
   defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.tsp.test"
      ...
   }
   ...
   flavorDimensions("customer", "version")
   productFlavors {
      a {
         dimension "customer"
         applicationIdSuffix ".a"
      }
      b {
         dimension "customer"
         applicationIdSuffix ".b"
      }
      alpha {
         dimension "version"
         applicationIdSuffix ".alpha"
      }
      beta {
         dimension "version"
         applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
      }
      release {
         dimension "version"
         applicationIdSuffix ".release"
      }
   }
   ...
   applicationVariants.all { variant ->
      variant.resValue "string", "ENTERPRISE_AUTHENTICATOR_ACCOUNT_TYPE", "\"${applicationId}\""
   }
}
...
```

This generate correctly the `resValue` with the package name of the selected variant.

For variant *customer* **A** and *version* **Alpha**, I get `resValue = com.tsp.test.a.alpha`.

Answer (score 1):

you must declear variable ENTERPRISE_AUTHENTICATOR_ACCOUNT_TYPE in gradle.properties like below

```
//default
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
ENTERPRISE_AUTHENTICATOR_ACCOUNT_TYPE=xxx
```

Comment: And what should I put for xxx ?
Because I have already seen proposals like that, the fact is I want to set the right package name depending on the build variant.

Comment: in what i see in your code you must replace xxx with your Application Id (com.tsp.test)

Comment: Ok, I get `com.tsp.test` (already try this solution) and next how I get the whole package name depending on build variant ? If I choose build variant with *customer* ***A*** and *version* ***Alpha***, my package name isn't `com.tsp.test` but `com.tsp.test.a.alpha`

Comment: oh, that get hard ! check this link . https://blog.davidmedenjak.com/android/2016/11/09/build-variants.html

Comment: Yes, I agree, a bit harder ! I will dig your link, thanks !