# Different app names for different build flavors in Android?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have 2 build flavors, say, flavor1 and flavor2

I would like my application to be named, say, "AppFlavor1" when I build for flavor1 and "AppFlavor2" when I build for flavor 2

Here is a my manifest source's snippet

```xml
<application
    android:name=".PApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Here is a gradle file's source snippet

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {

        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
        flavorDimensions "default"
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 25
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }

        signingConfigs {
            release {
            }
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }

        productFlavors.whenObjectAdded { flavor ->
            flavor.ext.set("app_name", "")
        }

        productFlavors {
            photographer_prod {
                app_name = "flovor1name"
                buildConfigField "String", "API_URL", ""
                buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_PHOTOGRAPHER_APP", "true"
                applicationId "me.flovor.package_1"
                versionCode 1048
                versionName "1.0.48"
            }

            agent_prod {
                app_name = "flovor2name"
                buildConfigField "String", "API_URL", ""
                buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_PHOTOGRAPHER_APP", "false"
                applicationId "me.flovor.package_2"
                versionCode 1016
                versionName "1.0.16"
            }


        }

        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            def flavor = variant.productFlavors*.name[0]
            def appName = variant.productFlavors*.app_name[0]

            variant.mergeResources.doLast {
                File valuesFile = file("${variant.mergeResources.outputDir}/values/values.xml")
                if (valuesFile.exists()) {
                    String content = valuesFile.getText('UTF-8')
                    content = content.replaceAll("app_name_string", appName)
                    valuesFile.write(content, 'UTF-8')
                } else {
                    println("File: " + valuesFile.path + " does not exist")
                }
            }

            if (variant.buildType.name == "debug") {
                return;
            }

            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                def SEP = "_"
                def buildType = variant.variantData.variantConfiguration.buildType.name
                def version = variant.versionName
                def date = new Date();
                def formattedDate = date.format('ddMMyy_HHmm')

                def newApkName = flavor + SEP + buildType + SEP + version + SEP + formattedDate + ".apk"

                output.outputFileName = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newApkName)
            }
        }
    }
```

In string.xml default value is

```xml
<string name="app_name">app_name_string</string>
```

When I try to build both flavors realize version, the app name is always  app_name_string (String from string.xml file)

How do i solve this problem? thanks

Comment: Simple google search gave me answer. here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830972/different-app-names-for-different-build-flavors

Comment: I read it, but in my case,how I can solve a problem ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add the string

```
<string name="app_name">app_name_string</string>
```

in the folders:

```
app/src/photographer_prod/res/values/strings.xml
app/src/agent_prod/res/values/strings.xml
```

You can also add resource values directly to your `build.gradle` file

```
productFlavors { 
    photographer_prod {
      resValue "string", "app_name", "the app name.."
    }
    agent_prod {
      resValue "string", "app_name", "the app name.."
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks your attentions. I'm not using flavor1/res and flavor2/res folders

Comment: @BekaKK of course you have to use the name of your flavors, instead of flavor1, flavor2. Just create these folders. Otherwise you can do the same with gradle, check the updated answer

Comment: I did not understand your answer correctly ,Can you show me  gradle source's snippet ? @Gabriele Mariotti

Comment: @BekaKK your comment is not clear. You can do it in many ways. For example just use different strings.xml for the different flavors (the only different strings not all the file), or use the resValue property in build.gradle. Both are described in the answer.

Comment: resValue use two parameters ,fist is app name and what's a second ? @Gabriele Mariotti

Comment: @BekaKK the last parameter is the value of the string in the xml. In your case the name of the app in the flavor.

Comment: resValue "string", "app_name", "my_app_name here  in Flavors1..",   resValue "string", "app_name", "my_app_name here  in Flavors2.." .. Right ? @Gabriele Mariotti

Comment: Yes and don't forget to remove app_name in `strings.xml`

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Gabriele Mariotti's answer, make sure application / `android:label` attribute's value is set to `@string/app_name` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: ... and it can even be in different language files.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `<string name="app_name">app_name_string</string>`.

Comment: I removed it ,but when I try to run project,project contains errors  @Bek